# MySQL Pull All records with join issue

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a weird situation. I've yet to find a solution to.I have tried using various joins and sub queries, so I'm a asking for a little help. I am using MySQLi and PHP 7.

I have two tables. One table (called table) contains a list of people. The other table contains a log of data that the person has done which is called reports.

I am able to select all the records plainly from each table without issue.
I am able to use a join statement to pull only records that are in both tables

What I am trying to accomplish is a query that will pull all records, but also join the data from the reports table while only showing the LATEST joined record from reports if applicable.

An example of the working join query:

```
select * from table 

 join reports on (table.ID = reports.ID)
 join contacts on (reports.cID = contacts.cID)

 where date(reports.dTime) = date(curdate()) and reports.Method = $methodID
```

An example of the modified query that does not work. I understand I may need to use a sub-query as my logic was flawed and OR does not work how I thought it would

```
select * from table 

 join reports on (table.ID = reports.ID)
 join contacts on (reports.cID = contacts.cID)

 where date(reports.dTime) = date(curdate()) and reports.Method = $methodID OR table.Method = $method
```

I have tried using LEFT OUTER JOIN as per the MySQL documentation, but can't seem to get it to include all records from table and any possible data from reports.

```
select * from table 

 left outer join reports on (table.ID = reports.ID)

 where date(reports.dTime) = date(curdate()) and reports.Method = $methodID
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? or is my grasp on Joins lacking?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

---

Edit - I just realized that I cannot possibly sort or order by the report times or method, because those may not exist, I do not need the ability to sort in this query. perhaps order by table.timestamp instead.

---

Edit 2 - Adding an example of expected results:

```
table
-------------------------------------
firstName | last Name | cID | dTime 
-------------------------------------
Jane      | Doe       | 312 | 10:30am 
John      | Doe       | 318 | 10:35am
Adam      | Doe       |  | 
Berry     | Doe       |  | 
Charlie   | Doe       |  |
```

The table Table contains various data about the person like name, age, etc. the contacts table just contains the contact ID (cid) and the contacts first and last name. The reports table contains the dTime, and a cid for that dTime which corresponds to the ContactID in the contacts table. Contact ID's are unique.

Comment: It is still a little unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you can add some example data and the expected outcome that would be helpful.  It sounds like a LEFT JOIN is what you need, which will give you all of the table rows, plus any available info from the joined tables

Comment: I will do that - editing now

Comment: @i-man  I have edited the question as requested

Comment: `table` is a reserved word in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: I used table as a placeholder - sorry. That is not my real table name. The real table name.

Comment: In your results, which table are the First and Last Name from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the data correctly, the query below should get you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT t.firstName, t.lastName, c.id, r.dTime
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN reports r ON r.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN contacts c ON c.id = r.cId
```

The relationship between Table and Reports does not appear to be setup correctly, unless you were simplifying your actual structure. As Binarus pointed out, you should have a tId column in the Reports table to store the Table id as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, you should always provide the *real* code you use. As you have seen (see @Jay Blanchard's comment), you will make mistakes if you randomly let out things or change names.

After all, you are posting here because you have an error somewhere, and the error will be at a place where you don't expect it. Otherwise, you would have found it yourself.

If you feel you can't disclose your real code for some reason, then there is no other way than creating [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a matter of attitude and respect towards all people who try to help.

The code you have shown won't run, and additionally, you really should tell us where `$method` and `$methodID` come from and how you computed them.

**Secondly, coming back to your problem,** I have noticed something which is quite unusual and which *might eventually* be a problem. I am unsure because you did not show your table definitions.

For the following, to make clear what I'd like to say, let us suppose that your table `table` actually has the name `persons`, and then let's look at your tables `persons` and `reports`.

Usually, in every table, you have a primary key, often called `ID`. When having a relationship between two tables, to enable the database to make a "connection" between rows from the two tables, you have to store the `ID` values of one table in the other table *in a separate column*.

In your example, this would mean that the table `persons` has a column `ID` and the table `reports` has a column `ID`, but the table `reports` additionally has a column `PersonID` where the `ID` of the person the row relates to is stored.

But according to your example, you are joining like that:

```
...
join reports on (persons.ID = reports.ID)
...
```

If you are using the usual method and the column `ID` in every table (including the `reports` table) actually is just the row ID (primary key), this does not make sense. Instead, you would have to join like that:

```
...
join reports on (persons.ID = reports.PersonID)
...
```

**Thirdly** (or would a native speaker say "third" here?), if you want to pull just the last record, you could use grouping with aggregate functions. To do so, make the following changes to your SQL statement:

```
SELECT ...,
       MAX(reports.dTime),
       ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY persons.ID,
         reports.cID
```

This will select all distinct pairs of `PersonID` and `cID`, and show the date / time of the last report for each such pair.

If you want to show the date / time of the last report per `PersonID` (and not per `PersonID` / `cID` pair), you could leave away the last line from the code above. But please be aware that the database will then select a *random* row from the matching rows in the `contacts` table if you still `SELECT` a column from the `contacts` table.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will run some samples and test and get back with you.